# How to target newer versions in .gitlab-ci.yml using auto devops (java 11 instead of 8 and Android 31 instead of 29)

Tags: android, java-8, gitlab, java-11, gitlab-autodevops

I'm utilizing the gitlab auto devops android template `Android.gitlab-ci.yml` [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Android.gitlab-ci.yml) but it's using a java 8 image (whereas I want to use java 11). Also, it has `ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK` set to "29" and I want to compile my app with the latest version - currently 31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another ["latest" template file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/cicd/templates.html#latest-version) named `Android.latest.gitlab-ci.yml` which can be found [on gitlab here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Android.latest.gitlab-ci.yml) . At time of writing it sets `image` to "openjdk:11-jdk" and `COMPILE_SDK` to "30". See [relevant gitlab MR/discussion](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/67595#note_669175833) for more context.

So, if you just want to use whatever is in the template, your `.gitlab-ci.yml` just needs to look like this:

```
include:
  - template: Android.latest.gitlab-ci.yml
```

That's all you need.

At time of writing that sets `ANDROID_COMPLE_SDK` to "30". So, if you want to bump that up and set it yourself, it's as simple as adding it to that file. For instance:

```
include:
  # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Android.latest.gitlab-ci.yml
  - template: Android.latest.gitlab-ci.yml

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "31"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "31.0.0"
```

Just remember that if/when someone updates the template to say, "32", you'll still be using "31". The choice is yours:

- Don't set any values (only use the `include`) and you'll get the update automatically when someone updates the template
- Do set/override some values. Updates won't be automatic, so you'll have to be sure to maintain them yourself