# What's the easiest way to enable gitlab auto devops for an android project

Tags: android, gitlab, gitlab-autodevops

What is the minimal set of steps to properly enable gitlab's "auto devops" feature for an Android project? After enabling the feature I get a pipeline but not the jobs I would expect such as `assembleDebug`, etc.

Steps taken to enable Auto Devops (clicking through gitlab UI):

```
gitlab -> project(git repo) ->
settings -> CI/CD -> 
Auto Devops -> Expand -> 
"Default to Auto DevOps pipeline" & "Automatic deployment to staging, manual deployment to production
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an "auto devops template" maintained [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Android.gitlab-ci.yml). Utilizing that file is as simple as creating a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file (at the root of your android project) and then `include` that file as the template you want to use:

```
include:
  # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Android.gitlab-ci.yml
  - template: Android.gitlab-ci.yml
```

That's it.

(To take it a step further and stay on the "bleeding edge" of java/android versions, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70083257/1399483))